# Updating a List of Object from another list of object using java stream

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a list of Object A

```
A{
name
age
dob
}
```

and list of Object B

```
B{
name
dob
}
```

.

I always get the List of A with A.dob as null. and List of B with B.dob having value. 
I need to loop thru List of A and List of B find the common objects using the name field in each A and B object and  update A.dob using B.dob

Can this be done using streams?

Comment: I think that goes against the principles of functional programming: streams are not meant for mutating an existing collection but rather creating a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use Stream APIs to change the state of an Object.

If you still want to modify it then,
You can iterate each element from the list of `A`, filter if dob is null, find dob against the respective name in the list of `B`.

```
List<A> aList = new ArrayList<>();
List<B> bList = new ArrayList<>();

aList.stream()
        .filter( a  -> a.dob == null)
        .forEach( a -> {
            Predicate<B> nameFilter = b -> b.name.equals(a.name);
            a.dob = findDob(nameFilter, bList);
        });

static String findDob(Predicate<B> nameFilter, List<B> bList) {
    B b = bList.stream()
            .filter(nameFilter)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(new B());

    return b.dob;
}
```

**Alternate  efficient solution:** Considering you have a unique name for each object B, you can prepare lookup and find age using that map, this way you do not need to iterate `bList` for every iteration of `aList`

```
List<A> aList = new ArrayList<>();
List<B> bList = new ArrayList<>();

Map<String, String> nameDobLookup = bList.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(b -> b.name, b -> b.dob));

aList.stream()
        .filter(a -> a.dob == null)
        .forEach(a -> a.dob = nameDobLookup.get(a.name));
```

Comment: This also worked for me, Thanks a lot. Now I have to see in terms of performance against each

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest modifying the list of A objects in a forEach loop:

```
// define: List<A> aList =

// define: List<B> bList =


aList.forEach(aListElement -> {
            // find the first B object with matching name:
            Optional<B> matchingBElem = bList.stream()
                    .filter(bElem -> Objects.equals(aListElement.getName(), bElem.getName()))
                    .findFirst();

            // and use it to set the dob value in this A list element:
            if (matchingBElem.isPresent()) {
                aListElement.setDob(matchingBElem.get().getDob());
            }

        }
);
```